# Include footer with with javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i Included a footer into index.html and i have the footer.html file.
The only issue is that I use the tippy tool tips plugin and it works in the footer when i have the footer without the include function but when i include it the plugin does not work anymore.

```
    <script>
$(function(){
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script>


<div id="footer"></div>

<div class="footer-copyright">
            <span>&copy; Lancashire Roleplay Community 2019 - All rights reserved</span>
            <span class="footerDev">Website Developed by <a href="mailto:mail" data-tippy-content="Tooltip">Adrian B.</a></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: try to move you script below the `div.footer-copyright`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the tippy tool invocation to after the loading

For example

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html",function() { tippy('#footer') }); 
});
```